# mysql view with spatial join not working

Tags: mysql, view, spatial, mariadb

I'm looking for some manner of workaround for a problem I'm having with views that include spatial relation clauses, specifically on 5.5.41-MariaDB. If not a workaround, then at least a confirmation that this kind of clause is unsupported in views. On to examples!

This select statement works

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM members m 
INNER JOIN ipDB ON Intersects(ipDB.ip_range, Polygon( LineString( Point(INET_ATON(m.signup_ip), 1), Point(INET_ATON(m.signup_ip), 0), Point(INET_ATON(m.signup_ip) + 0.5, 0), Point(INET_ATON(m.signup_ip) + 0.5, 1), Point(INET_ATON(m.signup_ip), 1))))
WHERE ipDB.name LIKE '%special%';
```

This create view works, too

```
CREATE VIEW debug_view AS (
 SELECT m.* 
 FROM members m 
 INNER JOIN ipDB ON Intersects(ipDB.ip_range, Polygon( LineString( Point(INET_ATON(m.signup_ip), 1), Point(INET_ATON(m.signup_ip), 0), Point(INET_ATON(m.signup_ip) + 0.5, 0), Point(INET_ATON(m.signup_ip) + 0.5, 1), Point(INET_ATON(m.signup_ip), 1))))
 WHERE ipDB.name LIKE '%special%';
)
```

However, this select of the view

```
SELECT * FROM debug_view;
```

Triggers this error:

```
Error in query (1356): View 'debug_view' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE VIEW` so we can check your `DEFINER` and `SQL SECURITY`.  Also, are the `VIEW` and the `TABLEs` in the same database?

Comment: In our actual problem, the view and the various tables it is made off are not in the same database, neither are those various tables.

    CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`user_name`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW ...

We've narrowed it done to either a permissions problem or a maria db bug as we found an example of this sort of view failing that we know worked when we were running plain jane mysql.

Comment: Please file a bug with mariadb.com